# Manipulating date format in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have the date with 2 formats **2001-11-28T06:00:00.000Z** and **10/20/09** in my Avro data  and I want to convert this to common format, How can we achieve this in  hive-0.10.0

I want to convert this to **2015-01-01 00:00:00** format

Answer (score 0):

Date functions in hive can be used

something like

`CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(column,'your-format'),"<desired-format>")AS STRING)`

for more help look here [Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

Comment: Not an answer. If you wish to answer, supply a working, tested code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting both formats in a single column, if that understanding is correct, create `input_column` as `string` and if table name is `test` then the query looks like

`select 
if (instr(input_column,"/") != 0 , 
from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(input_column, "MM/dd/yy"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") ,
from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(input_column, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) 
from test;`